# How to disable server in runtime in haproxy when nbproc >1

Tags: haproxy

We are using *haproxy* in *Multiprocess* environment (*nbproc 20*). We want to disable some server on fly from *haproxy* without restarting. We can easily do this with below command when `nbproc = 1`

```
echo "disable server Backend/ServerName" | socat stdio /var/run/haproxy/haproxy.sock
```

How we can do same when `nbproc > 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create separate sockets for each nbproc

```
stats socket /var/run/haproxy.1.stats mode 600 level admin process 1
stats socket /var/run/haproxy.2.stats mode 600 level admin process 2
stats socket /var/run/haproxy.3.stats mode 600 level admin process 3
```

and then redirect your socat/nc commands to  all the /var/run/haproxy.*.stats with a for loop or the way it best suits you like

`for socket in /var/run/haproxy*.stats; do
   echo "set server <FARM NAME>/<HOST NAME> stat maint" | socat stdio $socket
done`

Same applies if you want ipv4@ sockets.

cheers!!